# Finding how many solutions there are for a system of 3 linearly independant rows with 7 variables over $\mathbb Z_{13}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose we have a linear and homogenous system over $\mathbb Z_{13}$, with 7 variables. Suppose after doing RREF on the coefficients matrix we have 3 non zero rows. How many solutions there are to this system ?

There are four more variables than there are equations, and because it's $\mathbb Z_{13}$ there are 13 possibilities for each of them, so is the answer $13^4$ ?

It seems too easy to be true and there's almost no actual linear algebra in this question.

Comment: sounds good to me.

Comment: Assuming you mean "three (non-zero) linearly independent rows:, the answer, just as in **any** other homogeneous linear system like  this one, is that its solution space's dimension is $$7-3=4$$, and thus there are $\;13^4\;$ solutions (i.e., the space is isomorphic with $\;\Bbb F_{13}^4/\Bbb F\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio oh I see, the rank nullity theorem.